# KDE waste bin issues

Tags: kubuntu, kde, trash, dolphin

This has completely bamboozled me.

The waste bin is empty in my dolphin yet I cant delete anything because its claims it full every time I try. I have tried emptying it and it makes no difference. Where is the waste bin located in file system?

Anybody else experienced this?

Comment: The "full" issue is because the disk if full. Try shift-delete.

Comment: The trash is at `~/.local/share/Trash/files`. Try `Shift-Delete` all files there.

Comment: @Adobe Why not adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trash is at `~/.local/share/Trash/files`. Try `Shift-Delete` all files there.

Even better - do it from command line:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files
```

Does it solve You problem?

Comment: There is nothing in that directory...?

Comment: Not even dot files? Then I suggest You install `trash-cli` and exec `trash-empty`.

Comment: There was 2 dot files yes. But no files that I could remove to free up space? Really pissing me off. Ill try that mate. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled on to this thread while trying to figure the same issue out on a Gentoo system.

For anybody else experiencing this, edit `.local/Trash/metadata` and change the `Size=` line to a value of `0`.

There must be a bug in KDE preventing this value from decreasing either when items are removed or restored so eventually it just maxes out.